# Using spring:message tag inside of form:input tag in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

I want to Internationalize the content of an attribute in my Spring MVC app, the snippet code from my JSP file :

```
<form:input type="text" path="someAttribute" title="something"/>
```

And it's working fine, But When I want to Internationalize like this :

```
<form:input type="text" path="someAttribute" 
title="<spring:message code="label.something"/>"/>
```

it seems wrong, since it throws a `org.apache.jasper.JasperException` Exception.
My question Is : How Can I internationalize the "Something" String inside of the title attribute in my `form:input` Tag ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JSTL tags

```
<c:set var="title"><spring:message code="label.something"/></c:set>
<form:input type="text" path="someAttribute" title="${title}"/>
```